# Is there a symphony with a Toccata and Fugue movement?

Tags: johann-sebastian-bach

An Albanian poet I'm reading mentions a "symphony" that, after a commercial break, resumes at Toccata and Fugue. I assume this is a reference to Stokowski's orchestral transcription of the Bach but it occurred to me there might be an actual symphony with a single movement entitled Toccata and Fugue.

Comment: At the time of Bach, *sinfonia* practically always meant an instrumental movement in e.g. a cantata, or  three-part pieces as opposed to the two-part as inventions. I did not yet find any sinonia from Bach, which was further partitioned into separate movements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely this "symphony" is fictional.

There are a number of symphonies with movements entitled either "Toccata" or "Fugue".

- The last movement of Charles-Marie Widor's *Symphony for Organ no.5* is titled "Toccata"
- The two movements of William Schumann's *Symphony No.3* are titled "Passacaglia and Fugue" and "Chorale and Toccata"
- The finale of Kaikhosru Shapurji Sorabji‘s *Second Organ Symphony* consistes of four parts: Prelude, Adagio, Toccata and a Fugue
- The sixth movement of Howard Blake's *Symphony No.2 "Toccata"* is titled "Fugue"